# Returning another Page Object from a Page Object function in webdriverJS / Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor, pageobjects

I am used to WebDriver Java approach for implementing Page Object pattern, which is described [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)
So everything in Java WebDriver Page Object pattern boils down to following:

> 1. The public methods represent the services that the page offers
> 2. Try not to expose the internals of the page
> 3. Generally don't make assertions
> 4. Methods return other PageObjects
> 5. Need not represent an entire page
> 6. Different results for the same action are modelled as different
>      methods

So I am concerned about point ***4.Methods return other PageObjects*** - 
**Can it be applied to webdriverJS or Protractor cases?**

The reason I am asking this is that I have not yet seen this approach applied to Protractor scripts - usually all specs(tests in jasmine) are intended for testing only ONE page, BUT not testing complete work flow (1.logging in 2.going into the system further to test a whole feature of a system, but not only one page)
E.g.:

```
MainPage=require('./MainPage.js');
var LoginPage = function() {
    this.userNameInput = element(by.id('login'));
    this.passwordInput = element(by.id('password'));
    this.submitButton = element(by.id('submit'));

    this.loginWithValidCredentials= function(userName, password) {
        this.userNameInput.sendKeys(userName);
        this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
        this.submitButton.click();
        return new MainPage();
    };

    this.loginWithInvalidCredentials = function(userName, password) {
        this.userNameInput.sendKeys(userName);
        this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
        this.submitButton.click();
        return this;
    };
};
module.exports = LoginPage;
```

1. Successful Login in to a page from LoginPage object: **loginWithValidCredentials()** function should return **new MenuPage object**
2. Unsuccessful Login in to a page from LoginPage object: **loginWithInvalidCredentials()** function should return **the same LoginPage object** (e.g. ***this***)

So basically I want to use this Page Object pattern in spec files like this:

```
var LoginPage = require('../pages/LoginPage.js');
describe('Login with username and password', function () {
    var loginPage = new LoginPage();
    var mainPage; 
  it('Logging in with VALID credentials', function () {               
  mainPage = loginPage.loginWithValidCredentials(
                    "username",
                    "password");
 **//interaction with mainPage goes here**
});
```

Comment: That all seems reasonable - what's the question? Is it not working?